pip install error: Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
Trying to install some basic Python packages (Pandas and Streamlit) and getting the following error. I've searched and haven't found a post with this exact error, but have tried several of the options for similar error none of which have seemed to work.
Python version:  3.11.0
windows 11
 Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pp_1gho0\pandas_c428c00413ef4d5aa6d90953699360e4 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pp_1gho0\pandas_c428c00413ef4d5aa6d90953699360e4\.mesonpy-xvkbs22n\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pp_1gho0\pandas_c428c00413ef4d5aa6d90953699360e4\.mesonpy-xvkbs22n\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pp_1gho0\pandas_c428c00413ef4d5aa6d90953699360e4
      Build dir: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pp_1gho0\pandas_c428c00413ef4d5aa6d90953699360e4\.mesonpy-xvkbs22n\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pandas
      Project version: 2.2.2

      ..\..\meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Could not parse vswhere.exe output

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pp_1gho0\pandas_c428c00413ef4d5aa6d90953699360e4\.mesonpy-xvkbs22n\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Tried pip install as I have a thousand times, and was expecting the package to be installed, but each seem to error at this same step with the 12 lines of output.

Uninstall then reinstall Python but go to the website, do not reinstall from the Microsoft App store. I tried uninstall/reinstall of Python from the app store, and for whatever reason, was getting the same error.
After uninstalling and reinstalling from the Python website, the download was no longer running into the error and was able able to pip install any/all packages I needed.
Have no idea the reason for this, and maybe no connection to the actual error, but this did solve my issue.
